# Reverse rendering of Urdu fonts

Tags: python, linux, fonts, tkinter, right-to-left

I am working on a project that is based on Urdu language in Ubuntu platform. I'm using Python language and have almost achieved my task.

The problem is that, the Urdu text is rendered in reverse order.

For example, consider the word `کام` (*which means work*)
consisting of the three letters: 
`ک` ,
`ا` , and
`م`

The output is rendered in reverse order as  `ماک`
consisting of the three letters:
`م`, 
`ا`, and
`ک`

When copying this text to Open Office or opening the generated XML file in Firefox,
the generated result is absolutely desired.

I Am using Python 2.6 IDLE, its working perfect with Windows platform, which clearly shows its not the problem of IDLE. Am working on TKINTER GUI library.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Isn't Urdu written from right to left? I am guessing that is where the problem might be. I know, this is hardly a pointer, but perhaps it has something do with that?

Comment: Yes, Urdu is written from right to left. Project is working fine with Windows platform. So, i do not think that it can be a issue over here. The Issue to me is that Ubuntu Font Rendering Engine is not rendering URDU font correctly where as OPEN OFFICE is rendering it correctly.

Comment: When you say `rendering is reversed`, where does this happen?

Comment: I have taken output in LABEL at GUI made using TKinter in Python. Its working fine with Windows Platform but not with UBUNTU.

Comment: Aah. In that case, I will re-tag the question in case someone might be able to help.

Comment: It doesn't appear that Tkinter can handle RTL text by default. Previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150053/python-tkinter-using-tkinter-for-rtl-right-to-left-languages-like-arabic-hebre

Comment: I guess Python uses Rendering Engine of Operating System since its working on Windows. Problem still is same. Either can I change Rendering Engine of UBUNTU? or is there any python GUI library or IDE that render font it self?

Comment: @Syed: Try searching for it. I think `PyGTK` handles this well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Arabic.  Tkinter is a Python interface for the Tk GUI toolkit, which unfortunately has [no support for bidirectional languages](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3158).

My solution was to use [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) instead.  wxPython is also nice because your application will look native on whatever platform it's used.

There's more information on Tk's lack of bidi support here: http://easygui.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/easygui-and-unicode/

Answer (score -1):

Use a toolkit that isn't terrible, such as PyQt, PyGTK, or wxPython.

Comment: Tk has its advantages: it's simple, and everything you need is included with Python (versus three components for PyQt or PyGTK). But yes, this is probably the best way to resolve this problem.

Comment: @Thomas: "Included" is relative. Tkinter actually uses TCL/Tk which is bundled with most Python downloads but isn't actually a part of Python per se.

Comment: True, but bundled and part of the default install is much more 'included' than three separate downloads, where there isn't a package manager to install it for you.

Comment: -1: Claiming Tkinter is terrible isn't useful for answering this question. This answer is as useful as saying "Use an OS that isn't terrible". Maybe Tkinter is terrible for you but it's quite well suited for a very large variety of very common problems. In fact, the OP says this works fine on Windows, so it's not (necessarily) a Tkinter problem at all.