# Right to left text in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I'm using a RTL language and I need my text to be RTL. Is there a way to do it? And How can I justify my text? Example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root,,font=('Tahoma',8))#I need RTL and Right justified text!
text.grid()
scrl = Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrl.set)
scrl.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150053/python-tkinter-using-tkinter-for-rtl-right-to-left-languages-like-arabic-hebr and http://wiki.tcl.tk/699

Comment: @furas while that question tackles the same problem, the given answer uses a terrible hack and is from 2 years ago. Surely there's a better solution than that, no? (not OP, just an interested bystander)

Comment: @furas Can you tell me about how to use justify? And I need a better answer such as `tkinter` internal methods.

Comment: Looking for the answer, I have to say that the docs for TKinter are horrifyingly bad, include partial explanations (or outdated ones) and bad links going nowhere (i.e. personally, I would drop TKinter entirely and look for an alternative)

Comment: I only show that there is problem with RTL. Problem was 2 years ago and probably it is still today. Maybe there is better solutin, maybe solution is even somewhere on SO but I don't know it.

Comment: I have the problem too. may be we have using another GUI toolkit for persian langauge.

Answer (score 3):

i modified your code and it's worked!..

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root,,font=('Tahoma',8))#I need RTL and Right justified text!

text.tag_configure('tag-right', justify='right')
text.insert('end', 'text ' * 10, 'tag-right')
text.grid()

scrl = Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrl.set)
scrl.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
root.mainloop()
```

in fact i add 2 lines code that set `justify=CENTER` for a `Text` widget fails: there is no such option for the widget.

What you want is to create a tag with the parameter `justify`. Then you can insert some text using that tag (or you can insert any text and later apply the tag to a certain region)... Good luck! :)

Comment: it does not change RTL logical flow.
RTL != justify; it's something completely different (that's sometimes mixed up)

Comment: Typo error remove extra comma text = Text(root,,

Answer (score 0):

1 Answer will solve that letters inside the word wrote correctly from right to left, but still, the new line position is on the left, and sentences do not begin from right to left like this example.

کلمات در فارسی باید حتما از راست شروع شوند نه از میان
صفحه ،  و خط جدید هم باید از طرف
راست شروع شود .

if you see the second line begins from the middle of the
page, like
this.
consider next line begins in the middle.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an direct answer for the current question; but is somehow related. In case of someone needs to write `RTL` in an `Entry` (Alternative to `Textbox` or `Input` in Tkinter) for **farsi (persian)**, **arabic** and/or other `RTL` languages; you can configure your `Entry` like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
ent = Entry(win, justify="right")
ent.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

[image]

- Note that: Chars of text is broken inside Entry; I don't know what exactly is wrong about this in **Ubuntu**; but as far as i know there should not be a problem in **windows**.