# How to right align Persian Text() widget and make it selectable in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, farsi

I'm trying to make a notepad using python for Persian/Arabic language but when I try typing something in Text() widget it starts writing from left to right but I want it to start from right to left.
I've tried justifying my Text() widget but if you write something Persian in it, you can't select a specific word in that string.
for example we have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m54oK.png) text and we want to select the word "تست" but something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSFKz.png) happens.

**Code:**

```
main= Tk()
main.title("Notepad")
main.geometry("644x788")

TextLoc = Text(main,width=644, height=788, font=(("Baloo Bhaijaan 2"), 10, "bold"), wrap=WORD)
TextLoc.tag_configure('tag-right', justify='right')
TextLoc.insert('end', ' ' * 10, 'tag-right')
TextLoc.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right to left text in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306726/right-to-left-text-in-tkinter)

Comment: @SylvesterKruin OP used that exact same technique of adding a tag and setting the tag `justify="right"`. I think OP already looked at that answer.

Comment: @Warner I don't know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44625272/11106801) will be useful but basically you can change how double clicking select works in `tk.Text` widgets.

Comment: @TheLizzard The solution I linked to works well for me; I can select words both by dragging and by triple-clicking. What system are you on, Warner? How are you selecting the text? It would help if you could describe what exactly you're doing that results in the second image.

Comment: @TheLizzard I'm selecting by dragging it, but this is happening: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/620166723273752607/937629918513217536/bandicam_2022-01-31_12-15-43-026.mp4

Comment: it works just fine with English but the problem happens when I write something in Persian like "سلام این یک تست هست".

Comment: @Warner That looks a lot like a bug in `tkinter`. If it is, you can't really do much about it.