# Tkinter right to left menu

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a GUI program using python with tkinter. I want to put menu items from right to left. is it possible? I tried grid, but I get Error 'it's a top-level window'.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import LEFT, RIGHT
from tkinter import W
menuBar = Menu(win)
win.config(menu=menuBar)
fileMenu = Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0).grid(sticky=W)
menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New")
```

Comment: You have to show a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you tried so others could recreate the error, otherwise you're just going to get down-votes and no answer.

Comment: I added a part of my code.

Comment: That error is thrown because you're trying to `.grid()` Menu. Just delete that grid part and it'll be okay. I don't know about making it RTL though. Also `.grid()` , `.place()` and `.pack()` return `NoneType`. so always use them on another line (otherwise your variable is going to be nothing really.)

Comment: I know that removing grid works.

Comment: What!? Then why did you put it there if you knew it throws an error!?

Comment: You don't use grid, pack, place or anything on a Menu! Even if there is an RTL option it's not going to magically happen by a command that will throw an error!

Comment: you said show me some codes and i added that code, and i know that does not work, but i want a solution to do some thing like that i.e. RTL menu.

Comment: You said: "I tried grid, but I get Error", I said: "show me so I could recreate the error" and I did. And turns out your error has nothing to do with the thing you're trying to pull off here, except the `fileMenu` that returns `NoneType` and I explained that.

Comment: Just curious why you would want a right to left menu?

Comment: @Mike-SMT By the looks of it (other questions) he/she is Persian. It's an RTL language, so he/she wants to make the menu RTL too.

Comment: @ROAR ah that makes sense.

Comment: Mike-SMT, It's right.

Comment: Just reverse the order that you add them

Comment: @Hippolippo that will help for part of the issue. The other part of the issue will require some way to anchor the menu items to the far right of the screen.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150053/python-tkinter-using-tkinter-for-rtl-right-to-left-languages-like-arabic-hebr?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 9):

There is not a built in way to do this but you can try to work around it with event bindings.

My below example will use a few bindings to try and manage the location of a menu.

One thing we will need is a `Toplevel()` window to house the menu.

Next we need to get rid of its buttons (`-`, `[]`and `X`). This can be done with `overidedirect(True)`.

Now that we cannot manually move the `Toplevel()` window we need to bind the `<Configure>` event to a function that will position the top level on the right most side of our main window.

Here is the binding:

```
win.bind("<Configure>", lambda x: win.after(0, move_menu(x)))
```

Here is the function:

```
def move_menu(event):
    x = (win.winfo_width() - menu_frame.winfo_width())
    z = (win.winfo_x(), win.winfo_y())
    xx = menu_frame.winfo_width()
    menu_frame.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % ((xx), 0, (z[0]+x+8), (z[1]+30)))
```

Next we will need to force the menu or rather the Toplevel window to stay on top of the main window. This can be done with `menu_frame.attributes('-topmost', True)`. However we encounter an issue when you click outside of the man window and that is the toplevel menu window stays on top of all programs outside of your tkinter app.

In order to manage this behavior we need another 2 bindings. One for event `'<Enter>'` and one for event `'<Leave>'`. This will allow us to toggle the `overrideredirect()` method when the mouse Enters and leaves the root window.

Here are the bindings:

```
win.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: win.after(0, manage_top_attr(x, True)))
win.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: win.after(0, manage_top_attr(x, False)))
```

Here is the function:

```
def manage_top_attr(event, tf):
    menu_frame.attributes('-topmost', tf)
```

With all that added to the program we can have a menu that sits on the right of the screen.

Code example:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.minsize(200, 200)
win.geometry("250x200")
menu_frame = tk.Toplevel(win)
menu_frame.overrideredirect(True)
menu_frame.attributes('-topmost', True)
tk.Label(win, text="").grid(row=0, column=0)

main_window_frame = tk.Frame(win)
main_window_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

def manage_top_attr(event, tf):
    menu_frame.attributes('-topmost', tf)

def move_menu(event):
    print (event)
    x = (win.winfo_width() - menu_frame.winfo_width())
    z = (win.winfo_x(), win.winfo_y())
    xx = menu_frame.winfo_width()
    menu_frame.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % ((xx), 0, (z[0]+x+8), (z[1]+30)))

win.bind("<Configure>", lambda x: win.after(0, move_menu(x)))
win.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: win.after(0, manage_top_attr(x, True)))
win.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: win.after(0, manage_top_attr(x, False)))

tk.Label(main_window_frame, text="Main window").grid(row=0, column=0)

menuBar = tk.Menu(menu_frame)
menu_frame.config(menu=menuBar)
fileMenu = tk.Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)
menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New")
menuBar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=fileMenu)
menuBar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=fileMenu)
menuBar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=fileMenu)

win.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

After you resize the window:

[image]

Now it doesn't behave perfectly and could probably use some work but its a start.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot create items on a menu from right to left.

Comment: Bad! that is stopped me using tkinter.

Comment: any suggestion, is it possible with pyqt?

Comment: @keramat: I have no idea. I've never used pyqt. You can create menu buttons and place them in a frame from right to left, though they will have a slightly different behavior from a standard menubar.