# colon misplaced by tkinter BiDi

Tags: python, tkinter, hebrew, bidi

I'm working on a cross-platform python GUI application, using tkinter.
I created a Label with a Hebrew text, ending with ':', but, on Windows - the ':' is placed at the start of the string: `שלום:` instead of `:שלום`.
I even tried constructing the string as follows:

```
hebrewString  = 'ש'
hebrewString += 'ל'
hebrewString += 'ו'
hebrewString += 'ם'
hebrewString += ':'
```

Debugging, step-by-step in the IDE (PyCharm) displays the construction of the string correctly - `:שלום`.
I understand that tkinter doesn't implement BiDi on Linux: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249474/hebrew-with-tkinter-bidi), so on Linux I'm using `bidi.algorithm.get_display(hebrewString)`, and it's displayed correctly.

Comment: `t = "a"` then `t += "b"` _is_ supposed to make `t` return `"ab"` unless `bidi` affects whole string structure of python.

Comment: Didn't quite understand the comment. I tried the '+=' to force the string to be 'logical' correct, I'll update the Q.

Answer (score 0):

The `+=` operator will simply append the string you give it to the variable you declare.

This means that saying:

```
hebrewString  = 'שלום'
hebrewString += ':'
```

Is the same as saying:

```
hebrewString  = 'שלום' + ':'
```

Which would return `שלום:`.

Instead you can do something like the below:

```
hebrewString  = 'שלום'  
hebrewString  = ':' + hebrewString

print(hebrewString)
```

---

If you simply run the below:

```
hebrewString = 'ם'
hebrewString += ':'

print(hebrewString)
```

You'll see that Python simply appends the colon to the end of the string, not the beginning as it should be in hebrew.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. 'שלום' is displayed in the editor (browser) already BiDi. The concatenated ':' should be added after the last 'logical' letter (which is 'ם'), and should be displayed :שלום. I've updated the Q, explaining why I did the += method, for debugging.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you that Python doesn't handle it grammatically correctly when using `+=` as you seem to think it does.

Comment: I'm using the colon in a tkinter Label ('Name:') followed by an Entry ('Joe'), so the colon should be at the end of the label-string: hebrewString  = 
 hebrewString + ':'. My problem is that on Linux, using the pybidi algorithm - the colon is displayed according to my logic... or am I missing something... hmmm