# how to change direction of entry and text elemens into rtl insted ltr python tkinter

Tags: python, forms, tkinter, text, direction

i have this form

```js
from tkinter import *
class entr:
    def __init__(self):
        frm = Tk()
        frm.title( "Myform" )
        frm.geometry( "600x600" )
        frm.config( bg = "blue" )
        self.entry1 = Entry(frm, borderwidth=5 , fg = "white" , bg = "green" , font = ( "tahoma" , 24 ),justify='right')
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.Var_text4 = StringVar()
        self.entry4 = Text( frm)
        self.entry4.pack()
        frm.mainloop()
e=entr()
```

but it gives for example "أهلا بكم!" in **text** and **entry** instead "!أهلا بكم" because the default direction is English or ltr of course, but I need to get Arabic or rtl direction instead!

Answer (score -1):

There is no official rtl-support in the default tkinter. For just moving the text to the right, you can use `justify="right"`.

There is a pypi module promising real rtl-support though:
https://pypi.org/project/AwesomeTkinter/
[image: arabic text correctly aligned]

```
import tkinter as tk
from awesometkinter.bidirender import add_bidi_support, render_text
root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root, font='any 20', justify='right')
entry.pack()

# adding bidi support for widgets
add_bidi_support(entry)

entry.set('السلام عليكم')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Arabic is supported in Tkinter by default, my problem is in the direction only, could you tell me how to mix the code in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150053/python-tkinter-using-tkinter-for-rtl-right-to-left-languages-like-arabic-hebr
 with my code to get rtl direction, as i am a beginner in python

Comment: The first answer has code which is not necessarily the best and might cause some problems. I provided you a module which would handle the rtl for you. But if you still want to use the code: copy and paste all the code in the first answer, then change `entryWidget` in the first 3 lines to your widget variable.

Comment: when trying to print "!السلام عليكم" it gives "السلام عليكم!" so the direction is not working

Comment: Did you copy the code from the other answer or use the proposed library?